# How to reference entity in Query in CrudRepository in Spring Data JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I want to fetch Entity from Database with Spring Data CrudRepository with a `findWithTitle()` method like this:

```
interface TasksCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT t FROM Task t WHERE t.title IS NOT NULL")
    List<Task> findWithTitle();
}
```

But I get

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "T" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT t FROM Task t [42122-199]
```

I can't find the cause why is that happening. From what I know this syntax should be working as expected.

This is how Task entity looks like:

```
@Data
@Table("task")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Task {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Set<Attachment> attachments;
    private Set<TagRef> tagRefs;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

And here's the schema for it:

```
CREATE TABLE task
(
    id          IDENTITY,
    title       VARCHAR(100),
    description VARCHAR(1024),
    created_at  TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at  TIMESTAMP,
);
```

Comment: Maybe try using `SELECT (t)` instead of `SELECT t`.

Comment: `"SELECT t FROM Task t ..."`... I think, if you have a column `t` in the table `Task`, then `"SELECT t.t FROM Task t..."` would work. I wouldn't create table aliases with the same name a column has, by the way. The error message states there is not column `T` (capital, why?), so check if there is one or not.

Comment: @menteith It didn't helped.

Comment: @deHaar - there is no such column. I've added schema/entity for Task.

Comment: Aren't you missing the @Entity annotation ?

Comment: @moilejter No, it's Spring Data JDBC

Comment: If there is no column `T` or `t` in `Task`, why do you try to select it? Do something like `"SELECT t.title FROM Task t WHERE ..."`? That would select the titles... If you want to select the entire row (entity), then try `"SELECT * FROM Task t WHERE t.title IS NOT NULL"`.

Comment: Ah - I thought that what you wanted would only work with Spring Data JPA, and Spring Data JDBC would know how to map columns to properties - but not the whole entity the way you mean it to... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use asterisk as @deHaar mentioned:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Task t ...")
List<Task> findTasks();
}
```

What is more if you want to perform JOIN query it is also possible to run with asterisk as well:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Task t JOIN Attachment a ON t.id = a.task")
List<Task> findWithAttachments();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Custom query use predefined **Spring JPA** method.
Please try the below approach.

```
interface TasksCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Long> {


    List<Task> findByTitleNotNull();
}
```

Modifications done:

- Removed Query annoytation
- Renamed the method to match JPA standard predefined service

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't supported by Spring Data JDBC

Comment: if you are using java 8 then u can try `Stream<User> findByTitleNotNull();`
reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/html/

Answer (score -2):

May be this will help you ,
COLUMN_NOT_FOUND_1 = 42122
The error with code 42122 is thrown when referencing an non-existing column.
 Example:
 CREATE TABLE TEST(ID INT);
 SELECT NAME FROM TEST;